# [Im]proper use of possessive in Spanish?

Tags: gramática, posesivos

I recently texted my (Spanish-speaking) girlfriend, saying

> Voy a mis padres

She corrected me, telling me instead that I should say

> Voy *con* mis padres

But, that appears to invalidate the meaning.  What I wanted to say (in English) was

> I'm going to my parents' [house]

("house" was implied but elided).  Thus, I re-texted her, saying

> Voy a *la casa de* mis padres

As a native speaker, the use of possessives in English seems natural and automatic, but this feature is lacking in Spanish.  My question is:

> **What is the most efficient way of using possessives like the above in Spanish?**

A less-important side-question:  How would a native Spanish speaker understand my original message?

For the record, I *am* aware of, and consider myself fluent with, Spanish grammar involving [possessives and body parts](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2593/) (way different than English!), and also I've reviewed [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15227) and [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12965).

Comment: See http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3609/a-lo-de-mi-abuela-donde-mi-abuela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: to convey the meaning you intended, you should have said:

> *Voy a lo de mis padres.*

And to your side-question: a native Spanish speaker would not understand your original message, though very likely they could make a guess, especially if they knew that your L1 is English (because they'd guess you were trying to mimic the English possessive structure).

Bear in mind this is an idiomatic construction. *Lo de alguien* is a fixed phrase: it always means "somebody's place". You can stretch the meaning a bit. For example, suppose you have a small store and you paid a guy to print your logo on a batch of fancy paper bags; now you have to go fetch them, so you can say: *Voy a lo de las bolsas.* This might be slightly weird depending on dialect. Many people would rather say: *Voy por las bolsas.* Or, closer to the original pattern: *Voy al de las bolsas*, i. e. literally "I'm going to the bags'", meaning "I'm going to the bags guy's place."

Again, remember *lo de (alguien)* is an idiom always referring to place of residence (or work). As a general rule, you don't use *lo* like this.

In a possessive, you can replace the noun (or noun phrase) by an empathic possessive pronoun, as I'm sure you already know:

- *Tu casa es muy grande. La mía es mucho más pequeña.*
- *No cabemos en mi auto. Vayamos en el tuyo.*

The above usage is different from your original situation because here you're not eliding but replacing, and you can't replace a noun phrase with a pronoun unless you have mentioned it before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - very informative, even for understanding the English way of things.

Comment: Oops, another side question for @pablodf76:  Would/should I always use the masculine "_lo_"?  After all, I'm going to the house (_la_ casa); is gender matching prescribed here?

Comment: @pr1268 No gender agreement here; it's a stock phrase. You'd only use *Voy a la de mis padres* if you were talking about someone else's house before and you needed to emphasize that it's your parents' house, not the other, that you're headed for. Also: *lo* is neuter, not masculine. Think of it as vaguely meaning *business* (as in "mind your own business"). *Tengo listo lo tuyo* = "I have your thing ready".

Answer (score 0):

Note that **a** and **con** are not possessives but **prepositions**. As in English, **prepositions** have a main meaning but sometimes it gets complicated to choose the right one.

Directly translated, **con** is equivalent to the English preposition **with**; the catch here is that **con mis padres** means **with my parents** but also means **to my parents' place**. The meaning depends on the context.

For example:
  - Voy **con** el médico - Voy **al** médico (is used too) - Voy **a lo** del médico (not used in México)

However, you cannot say ***voy a mis padres**. In México, most of the time we use **con** to say that we are moving towards other people´s whereabouts.

---

To answer you side question, I believe that you were understood based on the context of you text communication; i.e. perhaps she new that you where going somewhere. Out of context, it would be difficult to tell what you meant.